Submit de form funciona apenas para o primeiro item do foreach
Olá, tenho um app com a feature de comentários em asp net mvc e criei uma partial view para exibir cada comentário. Nela tem esse form:


<form id="like-form-@commentId" method="post">
    <button id="like-button-@commentId" type="submit" class="btn p-1">
        <i id="like-icon-@commentId" class="fa-regular fa-thumbs-up"></i>
    </button>
</form>



Feito isso, adicionei na tag script da partial o seguinte:


let form_like = document.getElementById("like-form-@commentId")
let like_icon = document.getElementById("like-icon-@commentId")

form_like.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    setClick(e);
})

function toggleLikeIcon() {
    like_icon.classList.toggle("fa-regular")
    like_icon.classList.toggle("fa-solid")
}

async function setClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch(`/Question/LikeComment?commentId=${@commentId}`, {
        method: 'POST'
    })
    const data = await response.json()
    if (response.ok) {
        toggleLikeIcon()
    }
}



A partial é exibida através desse foreach na view principal:


@foreach (var (comment, userName) in Model.CommentsWithUserNames)
{
    var commentId = comment.CommentId;
    var numberOfReplies = Model.ReplysWithUserNames.Count(tuple => tuple.Item1.CommentId == commentId);

    @await Html.PartialAsync("_CommentPartial", new Tuple<Comment, string>(comment, userName))
    ;
}



O problema é que o script da partial só realiza o submit do form no primeiro comment do foreach, para os que subsequentes não. Fiz a diferenciação dos id's das tags do html para cada comment usando c#, suspeitei que pudesse ser apenas um problema, mas não surtiu efeito.

Seu código javascript esta sendo duplicado.  da uma inspecionada pelo navegador no código que foi gerado. voce precisa colocar o metodo setClick na sua view principal e passar o id do comentario como parametro.
